# All appointments have a different row (sap.m.PlanningCalendar)

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to port my old application with "sap.me.OverlapCalendar" to the new "sap.m.PlanningCalendar", I want to show appointments just for one person. I found a difference in the way the appointments display.

The template I use is:

```
var oTemplateRow = new sap.m.PlanningCalendarRow("RowTemplate", {
        appointments:[
        new sap.ui.unified.CalendarAppointment({
            startDate: {
                path: 'CalendarModel>DateFrom',
                formatter: util.Formatter.toStartDate
            },
            endDate: {
                path: 'CalendarModel>DateTo',
                formatter: util.Formatter.toEndDate
            },
            title: "{CalendarModel>CardName} - {CalendarModel>ProjectName}",
            text: "Gewerkte uren: {CalendarModel>WorkedHours}",
            type: "Type04",
            tentative: false,
            key: "{CalendarModel>ReportID}"
        })]
});
```

Which is bound to the Calendar control with:

```
bindAggregation("rows", "CalendarModel>/Items/", oTemplateRow);
```

The data is showing in the calendar but the way it shows is different.

Old calendar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaNQR.jpg

New calendar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfvSH.jpg

What should I do to get the same output?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the model: for example, at the root of the model you create an array corresponding to rows of the calendar, and each row should contain an array of appointments.
A sample json file can look like this:

```
{
    "items": [{
        "title": "Item1",
        "appointments": [{
            "text": "appointment1",
            "start": "2017-02-17T09:30:00",
            "end": "2017-02-17T13:00:00"
        }, {
            "text": "appointment2",
            "start": "2017-02-17T09:45:00",
            "end": "2017-02-17T13:10:00"
        }]
    }, {
        "title": "Item2",
        "appointments": [{
            "text": "appointment3",
            "start": "2017-02-17T10:30:00",
            "end": "2017-02-17T14:00:00"
        }, {
            "text": "appointment4",
            "start": "2017-02-17T10:45:00",
            "end": "2017-02-17T14:10:00"
        }]
    }]
}
```

"items" is an array of calendar rows, and each item contains array of appointments. The binding of the control should be more complex. I used such a file a base for JSON model and the controller code looks like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("QuickStartApplication.controller.View1", {

        onInit: function() {
            var oCale = this.getView().byId("PC1");

            var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("CalendarModel");

            this.getView().setModel(oModel, "CalendarModel");

            var oTemplateRow = new sap.m.PlanningCalendarRow("RowTemplate", { title: "{CalendarModel>title}" });

            oTemplateRow.bindAggregation("appointments", {
                path: "CalendarModel>appointments",
                template: new sap.ui.unified.CalendarAppointment({
                    title: "{CalendarModel>text}",
                    startDate: {
                        path: "CalendarModel>start",
                        formatter: this.toDate
                    },
                    endDate: {
                        path: "CalendarModel>end",
                        formatter: this.toDate
                    }
                }),
                templateShareable: true
            });

            oCale.bindAggregation("rows", {
                path: "CalendarModel>/items",
                template: oTemplateRow,
                templateShareable: true
            });

        },

        toDate: function(sValue) {
            if (sValue) {
                return new Date(sValue); //
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Note that first you create a row template and then bind its "appointments" aggregation to the "appointments" property of "CalendarModel" model with template for CalendarAppointment creation. Then you create a binding for calendar rows referring to the row template.